# Passing JSON URL data to .ejs view in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I have got a small Node.js app running which makes a request to a URL containing the current weather forecast, and I can successfully console log the JSON data, but am stuck on how I could pass this data to an .ejs view? For example, extracting just the temperature or the weather condition so that I can display it in a div? Have been searching through Google but have had no success! I have included my index.js file and index.ejs file below. Thanks in advance!

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=3a3188bfc5bb7c5d2eff1a4985214289'

request(url, (error, response, body)=> {
if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
const info = JSON.parse(body)
console.log("Temp: ", info)
} else {
console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode)
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('index', {info});
});

});

app.listen(8010);
console.log('8010 is the running port');


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body class="container">

    <header>
      <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <% info.main.temp %>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
     <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try `res.render('index', {info: info});`

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the nesting - in other words, make the request to the weather API in the body of your request listener. That way, every time someone requests the index page ('/'), the page will be populated with the most up to date weather:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=3a3188bfc5bb7c5d2eff1a4985214289';

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    res.render('index', { info });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're executing your javascript in the template, but you're not returning the output to an HTML string:

```
<main>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <%# this runs javascript %>
        <% info.main.temp %>
    <%# this returns an HTML string %>
        <%= info.main.temp %>
  </div>
</main>
```

**From the docs:**

> You'll notice everything inside <% %> tags is executed and everything inside <%= %> tags inserts itself into the returned HTML string.

http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

code in server.js

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var info = {
    key: "value",
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
};
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        info: info
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

code index.ejs:

```
<html>
    <% if(locals.info){ %>   
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.infoObject =<%-JSON.stringify(info)%>;
       console.log( window.infoObject);
   </script>
    <%}%>
    <body>
        <div> <% if(locals.info){ %> 
      <%=JSON.stringify(info)%>;
      <%=info.key%>;
 <%}%></div>
    </body>
</html>
```